# AngularStrap parseOptions helper differs from AngularJS ngOptions parser

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

The AngularStrap (v2.2.4) parseOptions helper does not seem to work the way the AngularJS (v1.4.2) ngOptions parser works.  I am not able to parse a string in AngularStrap which works fine in ngOptions.

This is the source data I wish to parse in AngularStrap is:

```
countryCodes = {
  "AF": "Afghanistan",
  "AX": "Aland Islands",
  "AL": "Albania",
  "DZ": "Algeria"
}
```

ngOptions parser will parse this string with no problems using this code in the `ng-options` directive:

```
k as v for (k,v) in countryCodes
```

The above string inside the html below works just fine:

```
<select ng-model="country" name="country" 
   ng-options="k as v for (k,v) in countryCodes" >    
</select>
```

Howevever, AngularStrap will not parse this string.  The code below fails:

```
<button type="button" ng-model="country" bs-select class="btn btn-default"
    bs-options="k as v for (k,v) in countryCodes">
</button>
```

The [AngularStrap documentation example](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects) uses a string format conforming to the ngOptions format in AngularJS, in particular the documentation uses

```
icon.value as icon.label for icon in icons
```

The format in the AngularStrap example attempts to parse an array of this format:

```
countryCodes = [
  {value: "AF",
   label: "Afghanistan"},
  {value: "AX",
   label: "Aland Islands"},
  {value: "AL",
   label: "Albania"},
  {value: "DZ",
   label: "Algeria"},
 ]
```

Looking at the [AngularStrap parseOptions module on Github](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/dist/modules/parse-options.js), it appears tehy are attempting to implement the same functionality found in AngularJS.

Am I doing something wrong, or does AngularStrap not parse objects for options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularStrap document states it only supports array data source for options.

"Available items are specified using the bs-options attribute. This attribute uses AngularJS ngOptions **array data source** syntax."

Comment: Can you point me to where you are reading this in the documentation?  Are you referring to the line _Available items are specified using the bs-options attribute. This attribute uses AngularJS ngOptions array data source syntax._

Comment: Yes, it is under Select -> Usage. http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/selects-usage. I can also confirm from the code they are using only array value function for parse function. If the input is not array the values are set to empty array.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  It would be nice for the documentation to be more clear that only the array portion of the ng options parser is implemented in angular strap.

Comment: I added [an issue to the library in Github](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/issues/1797).  The author(s) have been pretty good about support, I suspect objects will be supported eventually.